# Contar dos columnas y sacar un resultado

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy estancado tengo una tabla '`empleado`' con dos columnas sección y `ptft`

En sección tengo vendedores y cajero y en `ptft` tengo `part time` y `full time`

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero contar cuántos vendedores son `full time`. Osea como resultado sea

```
Vendedoresfull
–––––––––––
3
```

O cuántos vendedores son part time

por hora tengo esto

```
SELECT COUNT(`seccion`) AS seccion 
FROM empleadores 
WHERE seccion='Vendedores'
```

solo me cuenta cuanto vendedores tengo en la columna `seccion`. pero como hago que me digas cuántos vendedores son `full time`

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: por favor edita y agrega lo que hayas intentado para que de este modo se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Usa una función de agregación, en este caso `COUNT()` y pásale como argumento la columna `ptft` pues es la que tiene registrado el tipo de empleado que es.
- Como usaste una función de agregación, vas a requerir hacer un agrupamiento para que recibas como resultado las columnas generadas, en este caso se *agrupa* por la columna `seccion` y la columna `ptft` que deberán estar presente en la parte del `SELECT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT seccion, ptft, COUNT(ptft) AS Listado
FROM empleado
GROUP BY seccion, ptft;
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Recomendaciones**

- No le coloques acentos a los nombres de tus columnas.
- De no ser necesario no le coloques símbolos como el `.` a los registros de tus tablas, como lo hiciste en el caso de `Cajero` lo cual considero es irrelevante.

Comment: Muchas gracias. sobre la recomendaciones sorry. es que lo estaba haciendo la pregunta con el celular y la imagen lo hice en un block de nota por eso errores. muy agradecido.